# How to use guava Predicates as filter in the java 8 stream api

Tags: java, collections, java-8, guava, java-stream

Guava [Predicates](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicate.html) can't be used out of the box as filter with the java 8 streaming API.

E.g this is not possible:

```
Number first = numbers.stream()
    .filter( com.google.common.base.Predicates.instanceOf(Double.class)))
    .findFirst()
    .get();
```

---

How ever it is possible when the guava predicate is converted to a java 8 predicate,like this:

```
public static <T> Predicate<T> toJava8(com.google.common.base.Predicate<T> guavaPredicate) {
  return (e -> guavaPredicate.apply(e));
}

Number first = numbers.stream()
    .filter( toJava8( instanceOf(Double.class)))
    .findFirst()
    .get();
```

QUESTION: Is there a more elegant way to reuse guava Predicates in java 8?

Comment: Just use `.filter(Double.class::isInstance)` - no wrapping needed.

Comment: Why do you think `Predicate` is not a functional interface?

Comment: Guavas Predicate contains 2 methods, a functional interface must have one. But thats not a problem here, cause the second method is 'equals'. I overlooked it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The method handle for the `apply` method of the Guava predicate is a functional interface which can be used as filter:

```
Number first = numbers.stream()
    .filter(Predicates.instanceOf(Double.class)::apply)
    .findFirst()
    .get();
```

Comment: IMHO it looks cleaner with Double.class::isInstance

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard For this specific case: yes, of course. But the question is about how to reuse any Guava predicate, `instanceof` is just a (suboptimal) example.

Comment: The explanation is a bit odd, maybe due to the wrong introduction of the question. Guava’s `Predicate` interface *is* a functional interface, but that’s completely irrelevant here. You can’t pass an instance of Guava’s `Predicate` directly to a method expecting Java 8’s `Predicate`, because they simply are two entirely distinct types, functional or not. But you can implement Java 8’s `Predicate` via a method handle to whatever method having a compatible signature because Java 8’s `Predicate` is a functional interface. It’s not the method handle which is a functional interface.