# Unable to apply a predicate

Tags: java, java-stream

When I run my application it gives me below error ,

```
java: incompatible types: com.google.common.base.Predicate<java.lang.String> cannot be converted to java.util.function.Predicate<java.lang.String>
```

In Pathselectors.regex("/error") line it says Required type:

com.google.common.base.Predicate

Provided:
java.util.function.Predicate

```
private Predicate<String> paths() {
        // Exclude Springs Basic Error Controller
        return Predicates.not(PathSelectors.regex("/error"));
    
}
```

Please help, thanks

Comment: What is unclear about the error? Required return type is `com.google.common.base.Predicate`, but you return `java.util.function.Predicate`. Most probably you imported the wrong `Predicate`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your imports - you probably have imported `java.util.function.Predicate`, which made the function's return type `java.util.function.Predicate`:

```
private Predicate<String> paths() {
//      ^^^^^^^^^
// this is java.util.function.Predicate
```

[`Predicates.not`](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Predicates.html#not(com.google.common.base.Predicate)) returns a `com.google.common.base.Predicate`, hence the error.

You should first make up your mind about which type of predicate your method should return.

If you want it to return `com.google.common.base.Predicate`, change your import to:

```
import com.google.common.base.Predicate;
```

If you want it to return `java.util.function.Predicate` (perhaps [because you want to use it in a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35701317/5133585) or otherwise), you can return the method reference to `apply`:

```
return Predicates.not(PathSelectors.regex("/error"))::apply;
```

---

Since the regex `/error` just matches the string `/error` literally, you could also just do (assuming `PathSelectors` is `springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors`):

```
return path -> !path.equals("/error");
```

in this case, and this will work for both types of predicates.

On the other hand, you might have meant

```
return path -> !path.startsWith("/error");
// or
return path -> !path.contains("/error");
```

which is not what your regex matches.

Comment: Since the string doesn’t even contain a regex special character, the OP might actually want `return s -> !s.contains("/error");` or `return s -> !s.startsWith("/error");` or such alike…

Comment: @Holger I didn't address that part because I wasn't quite sure what `PathSelectors.regex` was actually doing. The first result on Google is `springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors`, and the `regex` method on that has uses `matches`, rather than `find` :D

Comment: I don’t know either, but that’s precisely why I suggested the alternative. Because I suspect what *the OP might actually want* is `return s -> !s.startsWith("/error");`, regardless of what that 3rd party method will actually do.

Comment: @Holger Ah I see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, I tried like the below code. It fixed the error
In my @Configuration class ,

```
 @Bean
    public Docket docket() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .select()
                .paths((java.util.function.Predicate<String>) paths())
                .build();
    }
private Predicate<String> paths() {
        // Exclude Springs Basic Error Controller
        return  Predicates.not((Predicate<String>)PathSelectors.regex("/error"));
    }
```